# index.ts file not finding same-level modules

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, typescript1.7

Firstly: in Visual Studio 2015 with Typescript 1.7.6.0. I am not an administrator of this machine so I am unable to install new Typescript versions to VS2015 on a whim.

This is my current project directory structure. Each file contains a single class or interface being exported with the same name as the file:

```
+src
|+Page
||-index.ts
||-IPageMedia.ts
||-Page.ts
||-PageImage.ts
||-PageMedia.ts
||-PageText.ts
```

My `index.ts` file contains this:

```
export * from './Page';
export * from './IPageMedia';
export * from './PageMedia';
export * from './PageText';
export * from './PageImage';
```

Intellisense is redlining each module name in `index.ts`, and the tooltip says "Cannot find module" for each module. My `Page` class imports the `IPageMedia` interface with no problem, and the `PageText` and `PageImage` classes both import the `PageMedia` class with no problems.

What gives?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so, uh... having a module file with the same name as its containing folder caused it. I renamed the folder to something else and problem solved.

[flips desk]